# X coordinates of each yAxis in HighStock chart

Tags: javascript, coordinates, highcharts

How can I find X position for each yAxis in my HighStock Chart? (some property like plotX and plotY in point object)

Comment: just to confirm, when you say x position do you mean the pixels or something else?

Comment: yes I mean pixel. I have multi yAxis and I want to render some svg items with renderer on them.

Comment: does [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels) help?

Comment: Thanks @RahulSharma. but I think this will convert y value of axis to pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the position of axis, from left/right object and offset. If axis is on the left then this is:

```
 axis.left
```

and if on the right:

```
chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth - axis.offset - axis.right
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/79gqnqqL/

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian. I used your solution for finding coordinates. but I have to try some changes and finally `chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth + yAxis.offset;`  worked for me.